# vec.push is not adding the elements to the vector in rust

Tags: file, rust, io, std

I am working on a music player and i wanted to iter over all the files and dirs inside a dir so
i wrote this code

```
    let mut paths = vec![];
    for entry in read_dir(path).unwrap() {
        let entry = entry.unwrap();
        let path = entry.path();
        if path.is_dir() {
            println!("FOund a dir : {:?}", entry.display());
            dbg!(&paths);
            paths.push(path.clone());
            dbg!(&paths);
            iter_dirs(&path);
        } else {
            println!("Found a file : {:?}", entry);
            dbg!(&paths);
        }
    }
    dbg!(&paths);
    return paths;
}
```

i though that it will print as well as return the paths to all the files and dir
but this program only prints the files but does not return them.

I am a begginer with rust so i know i would have made a pretty silly mistake.

I was expecting the function to print and also return the PathBuf's for all the files and folder inside a dir

But it also prints then and does not return them

Comment: Please give an example of a directory structure, the expected output and the actual output. Also, how you are calling this function, including the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a begginer with rust so i know i would have made a pretty silly mistake.

Your code is woefully incomplete, but assuming this is the body of the `iter_dirs` function declared thus:

```
fn iter_dirs(path: &Path) -> Vec<PathBuf>;
```

- you only append paths to the return vec in the dir case, in the file case you just ignore them
- you don't add the *sub* paths to the vec:

  ```rust
  iter_dirs(&path);
  ```

  the subpaths collected here are just dropped on the floor

As a result, all that gets returned is the immediate subdirectories of the path you originally give.

That aside, this is a very inefficient method of iteration, you should probably use [the walkdir crate](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/).

Comment: Yes being a begginer sucks but thanks